# How to effectively use current_user in flask-login without resorting to pymongo query?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, flask-login

I currently use flask-login for my application. Now, after the user logins, according to the documentation, I have a current_user object that I can access in any route. The problem is, this current_user object cannot directly access the document on mongodb in which the user information is stored. To get the information I have to do like this:

```
user_collection.update_one({"username": current_user.username}, {"$set": {"assigned_username": assigned_username}})
```

I don't want to do it every single time though as it seems horribly inefficient. Is there a better way to use current_user to get info from database?